# Python - How to enable cookies for web scraping with Requests?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I have a script to scrape a website which works perfect on my local computer. When I deployed it to a server same script can not get data from target server.

I have enabled debug and noticed that target server gives an error message: "Cookies must be enabled".

Following is the code snippet. Python version 2.7.3 is running on both local computer and server.

I will appreciate you support for a solution.

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://targetsite.com'

CLIENT = requests.session()

detail_page = CLIENT.get(BASE_URL, headers=HEADERS, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: Incidentally the question has zero to do with bs4, and everything to do with the `requests` library.

Comment: Does it fail on your first request? Normally a cookie is returned which can then be used in later requests.

Comment: The thing is, this *ought* to work - however I suspect there is some JS stuff going on... Impossible to know since we're not told the actual address.

Comment: It is enabled by default as [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies) implies.

Comment: Although my script does not get any error message; can it be related wiht a python module which might be missing or outdated? If so how can I make sure I have all the required modules on my server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be with the target server. I have changed the user agent to a search engine, than problem is solved. I also understand that it is not related with the cookie but target server was giving a wrong error code..